# expire=0 in multiple contact REGISTER + SIP

Tags: sip

Hi i have query about SIP as below:

If we try to REGISTER and DEREGISTER(means expire=0) in multiple contacts of same REGISTER request like:

Contact: ;+g.oma.sip-im;+g.3gpp.smsip;q=1.0
Contact: ;expires=0

But,
there will be conflict since both registration and deregistration is happening in single request ,where this will
end up with neither sending contact in 200ok(means register) nor not sending contact in 200ok(means deregister)...

What should be the behavior???????

Thanks,
Naveen

Comment: Hard to tell what you need exactly

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking you are trying it as a random test case to break a spec here.

The intent shall be defined by the Server handling it. If its sequential in Contact processing it shall end with what it processes last.

The more important question is knowing why the entity registers with the format you have specified.

I see merit in doing the reverse if the Server wants to give a fresh lease to the registrations. Again the order is totally dependent on the REGISTRAR.

1. Flush all my previous registration
2. Do just specific Contacts i have here.